# Hector SLAM minimum requirement spec

Tags: slam, navigation, mapping, hector-slam, hector-mapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi! I want to use hector mapping on board computer such as Q7-BT, BeagleBone.
so I have to select CPU and RAM. Please tell me minimum requirement CPU and RAM spec to run hector mapping.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/215522/hector-slam-minimum-requirement-spec/) by [masa](https://answers.ros.org/users/23521/masa/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2015-08-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

While I haven't used it in a live mapping setup on the Raspberry Pi so far, I tried processing a bag file on a Raspberry Pi2. That consumed 10% CPU of one core on the Pi, so it looks like it's worth trying out on similar platforms.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2015-08-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1